# Localization in Cordova+WinJS application

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, localization, winjs, msdn

I'm try to build sample WinJS application with "WinJS Navigation Template for Apache Cordova" ( https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WinJS-Navigation-Template-50112ea9/view/SourceCode ).

What is a right way to add localization to this application? Standard for WinJS way - use strings/en-US/resources.resjson - doesn't work.

Comment: Why wouldn't the standard way work?

Comment: I don't now. WinJS.Resources.getString('greeting') return {empty: true, value: "greeting"}. resourses.resjson has key "greeting".

Comment: Then you must have bug of some kind. Either your user interface language is set different than what is found on the existing locale files or then the locale files are formatted incorrectly. If you shared everything related to that, maybe that could be solved instead of doing it some other way..

Comment: Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.languages // return 'en-US' Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.manifestLanguages // return 'en-US' - Link to project https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1849174/CordovaNavigationTemplateWithL10N.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason `WinJS.Resources.processAll()` does not seem to work in a Cordova app is because the WinRT runtime is **not available** in browser-hosted applications.

This is not directly written in the documentation, but is implied in the [Application resources and localization sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Application-resources-and-cd0c6eaa/sourcecode?fileId=43559&pathId=1048832723):

```
// WinRT is not available in the web compartment, so we must load strings ourselves 
// File based resources can be used to load the correct strings 
WinJS.xhr({ url: '/strings/resources.json' }).done(function (response) { 
    strings = JSON.parse(response.responseText); 

    WinJS.Resources.processAll(); 
    showMessage(); 
});
```

Comment: For Windows 8+ and Windows Phone 8.1 +, Cordova Apps run as native apps, because those platforms support native JavaScript. As such, WinRT is available and should work. (Windows Phone 8 that still runs in a web context.)

Comment: Hi Kraig, I am running into the same issue as potapuff, with the difference I have been using Windows 10, and the only way that I have gotten localization to work is by using the workaround. Will create sample project and post it this weekend.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the processing for those locale file resources. It should be on the `pages/home/home.js` on *ready* handler. Like this

```
ready: function (element, options) {
    WinJS.Resources.processAll();
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This makes use of the localizations and replaces those to places where they are used.

Comment: Yes. This solution must work. But in my case (I don't know why) it won't work until I do hard resource fetch in index.js: var p = WinJS.xhr({ url: "./strings/" + Windows.Globalization.ApplicationLanguages.languages[0] + "/resources.resjson" })
          .then(function (response) {
              window.strings = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
        }).then(ui.processAll) .... any else solution, like WinJS.Resourse.processAll.then(ui.processAll).then ... doesn't help me.